# pdfminer pdf2text outputs 'FF'

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer, pdf-parsing

[image]

I have a pdf. After installing pdfminer.six in my win 10,  python 3.6 environment, I ran:

```
$ pdf2txt.py -o test1 download.pdf
```

Giving me the screenshot output. When I run:

```
$ dumppdf.py -o test2 download.pdf
```

I get:

```
<trailer>
<dict size="4">
<key>Info</key>
<value><ref id="47" /></value>
<key>ID</key>
<value><list size="2">
<string size="16">+&#13;N&#158;&#213;&#233;&#197;&#176;&#8;&#207;&#15;&#60;&#133;M&#140;&#4;</string>
<string size="16">&#34;&#179;&#255;&#28;&#221;&#234;&#177;&#39;&#166;&#133;&#15;&#214;&#237;&#25;&#196;&#205;</string>
</list></value>
<key>Root</key>
<value><ref id="46" /></value>
<key>Size</key>
<value><number>48</number></value>
</dict>
</trailer>

<trailer>
<dict size="4">
<key>Info</key>
<value><ref id="47" /></value>
<key>ID</key>
<value><list size="2">
<string size="16">+&#13;N&#158;&#213;&#233;&#197;&#176;&#8;&#207;&#15;&#60;&#133;M&#140;&#4;</string>
<string size="16">&#34;&#179;&#255;&#28;&#221;&#234;&#177;&#39;&#166;&#133;&#15;&#214;&#237;&#25;&#196;&#205;</string>
</list></value>
<key>Root</key>
<value><ref id="46" /></value>
<key>Size</key>
<value><number>48</number></value>
</dict>
</trailer>
```

What do I do next? How can I get this working?

Comment: Update your PDF link so it is accessible without the need to login into any app.

Comment: Does this work ?

Comment: "This document has been removed from Scribd." --- Usually public shares on google drive or dropbox work fine.

Comment: How about this?

Comment: That share can be downloaded. Next please indicate what you expect to achieve? That Foreclosure Worksheet PDF does not contain text drawing instructions, merely graphics drawing instructions (the results of which look like text), so PDF text extraction will return nothing. You had better go for OCR instead of text extraction.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to remove the link, if you can see what I covered over. As someone who knows very little about PDFs, how do you know that only graphic instructions are contained? What tools do you use?

Comment: *"I'm going to remove the link, if you can see what I covered over"* - you correctly say that you covered over all that, you essentially appended instructions to the pdf content stream which tell pdf viewers to draw filled rectangles over the content. By removing those added instructions, everything was clear to see. In such a case you need a true redaction tool.

Comment: *"how do you know that only graphic instructions are contained"* - I'll make any answer on that topic later today.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why pdfminer can not extract any usable text from the document in question is that the document does not contain text!

More exactly, that Worksheet PDF does not contain *text drawing instructions*, merely *graphics drawing instructions* (the results of which look like text). PDF text extractors (like pdfminer), on the other hand, are inspecting only the *text drawing instructions*, so they will return nothing.

To mine data from such documents, therefore, you had better go for OCR instead of text extraction.

---

In a comment you asked

> how do you know that only graphic instructions are contained? What tools do you use?

You need a PDF browser application and some knowledge of PDF internals.

As PDF browser I usually use [iText RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/Products/itext-rups) or [PDFBox PDF Debugger](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#pdfdebugger). But there are other good browsers, too, e.g. there is one included in Adobe Preflight.

Using such a PDF browser you can inspect the content streams of the PDF which contain the instructions for drawing the pages. And in your case these content streams do not contain any text drawing instructions, merely graphics drawing ones.

The knowledge of PDF internals one can get by studying the PDF specification ISO 32000-2 (the old precursor specification ISO 32000-1 is a good starting point, too, if the newer spec is not at hand) and analyzing many real-word PDFs by it.

Comment: I've since learned that this document has likely been scanned. Is it possible to extract the original scanned image/jpg from this pdf ?

Comment: Most likely there are python pdf libraries to do so. Unfortunately I do not know because I don't process pdf files in python. BUT if I remember correctly, the page in your pdf is not stored as a single large image resource but instead as a mosaic of many small ones. That is not completely uncommon among scanner outputs as some scanners attempt to do an analysis of the image and split it to allow a more compact storage.